# RecyclerView overlays ImageView on scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecylerView` that is below an `ImageView`:

[image]

I'd like for the `RecyclerView` to scroll over the `ImageView` when the user scrolls down the list. If they scroll back to the top the `ImageView` should be displayed. I know I can accomplish this by adding the `ImageView` to the list of items but I don't want the `ImageView` to scroll with the list, it should stay in place and the `RecylerView` covers it.

This is what I have for the layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/episodes_list_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/episode_list_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/episode_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/episode_list_progress_text_thumbnail"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This list of items are being populated with a custom `RecyclerView.Adapter` but I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: Admittedly, the duplicate I've added is a little dated, but easy to update; better use a `com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Comment: Thank you. I was searching for "recyclerview overlay view on scroll" and nothing came up. Just needed to know of the name of the widget.